# Leafletjs detect click/touch on layer

Tags: leaflet

How do I detect a click on a layer and find out information about the layer that was clicked?

Currently I can do the usual binding a popup and adding a click handler on the layer:

```
L.geoJson(data.streets, {
    onEachFeature: function(feature, featureLayer) {

        featureLayer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);

        featureLayer.on('click', function(e) {

            console.log('Layer clicked!', e);
        });
    ...
```

However the click handler on the layer doesn't give me any information about the layer, just the following:

```
containerPoint: o.Point
latlng: o.LatLng {
    lat: 50.804443085898185,
    lng: -1.089920997619629 
}
__proto__: Object
layerPoint: o.Point
originalEvent: MouseEvent
target: e
type: "click"
__proto__: Object
```

How can I get a reference to the layer it's clicking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was assigning layers to a featureGroup, I needed to put the click handler on the featureGroup in order to get a layer reference returned. Putting it on the individual layer didn't work.

Comment: Any chance you could share some code for this?

Answer (score 4):

the layer is available from the event; in your case `e.layer` returns the layer

alternatively, you save the layer to a variable when you construct it with L.geoJson, then bind your click event later:

```js
var streets = L.geoJson(data.streets, {
    onEachFeature: function(feature, featureLayer) {
        featureLayer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);
    })
)}
streets.on('click', function(e) { console.log(e.layer) });
```

This might be better; as it is now, I think you are binding a click event to the layer for every feature, which is probably not what you want to do.

Comment: I don't get a layer returned, see above. I'm clicking on a polyline if that makes a difference.